# How to set idleTimeout for iisexpress?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I set the idleTimeout in processModel in applicationhost.config but it doesn't work.it seems follow the another property to abort the thread after a determined idle time .I think the idle time for this case is about 10 minutes.
notice idleTime,session timeout and cookie timeout are changable for IIS as well but in this case iisexpress is matter for me.
how can I do that for the iisexpress?

Comment: As lex li said,IIS Express is a lightweight, self-contained version of IIS optimized for developers. In IIS, the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) silently activates and deactivates Web applications and the user has no direct control. In IIS Express, there is no WAS and the user has full control of application activation and deactivation.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview#iis-express-and-iis

Comment: Thanks @BruceZhang.I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express is a single process web server, so not all of application pool settings are not applicable to it. So if you want to test `idleTimeout`, you have to be on full IIS.

Comment: I use IIS Express for my solutions local testing using VS instances. So how to prevent application pool from restarting in 20 mins while executing some long-running job?